# Ruby/Rails equivalent of Python's sys.addAuditHook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, audit-logging

I am a total beginner to Ruby and am hoping for some advice. My goal is to log all (for example) socket operations with a Ruby program with as little code modification as possible.

As a tiny example, pretend I have a super simple server like so:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2017)
loop {
    client = server.accept
    client.puts "hello world"
    client.close
}
```

In python, I could use `sys.addAuditHook` to catch the socket operations (open/write/etc) buried somewhere within the depths of `TCPServer.open`/`server.accept`/`client.puts` without having to resort to wrapping the entire TCPServer api or something like that.

I am interested in system events, not object writes, so Rails' Active Record Callbacks doesn't look like what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know if there's anything remotely equivalent for Ruby/Ruby on Rails, or am I stuck doing this the slow way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ruby doesn't have that level of logging built in. The bulk of that use case is generally achieved through [APM/instrumentation tools or services](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_instrumentation), but those generally target higher level (gem) libraries, rather than the low level stdlib stuff.